# ng-pattern with regex having double quotes does not escape correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern, angularjs-ng-pattern

I have a ng-pattern validation for a regex of ^[^\./:*\?\"<>\|]{1}[^\/:*\?\"<>\|]{0,254}$ which basically tests the invalid chars in filepath and teh limit. but when i have the ng-pattern specified as

```
 ng-pattern = "^[^\\\./:\*\?\"<>\|]{1}[^\\/:\*\?\"<>\|]{0,254}$"
```

, the ng-pattern shows the regex in an incorrect way. any help on achieving this correctly

Comment: In javscript, a regex is wrapped with the / character. Have you tried changing the quotes to backslashes? `/^[^\\\./:\*\?\"<>\|]{1}[^\\/:\*\?\"<>\|]{0,254}$/`.

Comment: you used  unescaped delimiter (/) this is why you got this error.

Comment: @jperezovI tried removing teh quotes at teh ends , it still does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your regex contains too many escaping symbols, while you only need to escape the `"` here and `\\`.

Then, to match a `"` inside `ng-pattern` attribute, you may define it as `\x22` or `&quot;`:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form">
  <p>Enter text to validate:</p>
  <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="name" ng-pattern="/^[^\\\\./:*?&quot;<>|][^\\\\/:*?\x22<>|]{0,254}$/" ng-trim="false" />
  <div ng-show="form.name.$error.pattern">Text doesn't match with ng-pattern!</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You may also solve the problem by defining a regex in the controller with a *regular string literal* where you may use `'.."..'` or `"..\"..."`, and then use the variable name inside `{{...}}` in the `ng-pattern` attribute. Note that to match a literal `\` you need to use 4 backslashes in the regex pattern.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("FormCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.regex = "/^[^\\\\./:*?\"<>|][^\\\\/:*?\"<>|]{0,254}$/";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <form name="theForm" ng-controller="FormCtrl" novalidate>
        <input type="text" name="filename" placholder="filename" ng-model="filename" ng-pattern="{{regex}}" required />
        <div class="error"
                     ng-show="(theForm.filename.$dirty || attempted) && theForm.filename.$invalid">
                  <small class="error text-danger"
                         ng-show="theForm.filename.$error.required">
                    Please enter a file name.
                  </small>
                  <small class="error text-danger"
                         ng-show="theForm.filename.$error.pattern">
                    Please enter a valid file name.
                  </small>
                </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to exclude ' and " in a ng-pattern which is similar to the problem above. I found a way to embed ' or " directly without having to use a scope variable:

`<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[^&#34&#39]+$/" />`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\&quot;` to escape `"`.